# Input Manager in Cocoa?

Tags: cocoa

Basically, I want to execute a method from my app whenever something else from another app happens. I know the name of the method from the other app, I just don't know how to make my app do something in response to it. Is an input manager the best solution?

Comment: Can you give context? Is the other app sending you a message? What's the other app? What are you going to do in response?

Comment: this is possible, but unless the other app intends to be observed you won't be able to do much without some mess. I don't think an input manager will help...

Comment: If it helps, I'm talking about iPhone Simulator. I want my app to do something in response to it rotating. I know the methods it calls when it rotates (toggleRotationLeft:/toggleRotationRight:), I just can't figure out how to do something in response to that code.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about an iPhone app running in the Simulator, or a Mac app that monitors the Simulator?

Comment: A Mac app that monitors the Simulator.

Comment: Is this for personal use, or for an app you'll give to others?

Comment: Personal use -- don't really care about the side effects ;)

Answer (score 0):

Generally No.
You can only do this if the other app is posting an `NSNotification` or otherwise exposes an API.

Otherwise Not very easily or gracefully. 
You could hack something together with a combination of `NSEvent` globalMonitor and `CGEventTap`
Either one could monitor for a condition where the active application is the one you want (in this case the simulator) and the relevant keyboard shortcuts have been entered.

This of course leaves menu item control for rotation...

Another way with CGEvent, is to monitor the window size and pay attention to the ratio. We know that all iOS devices including the simulator versions have non-square aspect ratios.
We know that OS X windows have a fixed title bar height.
You could interpret the `CGWindow` window list key `kCGWindowOwnerPID` and match it to the `NSRunningApplication` `processIdentifier`then manually try to monitor the change in the window list key `kCGWindowBounds`
You could reduce the checking frequency of the window bounds by watching for mouse down events that happen in the area of the OS X toolbar hight. 
You could further narrow these to be some distance x from MinX to assume they are not other menus.

This would still leave the gap of full keyboard control being turned on (a lot more stuff to try and interpret), as well as the gap of a mouse down event in the menubar, followed by keyboard events to navigate the menus.

Lastly, you could try the Accessibility APIs (AX prefix) to better identify things. These are even harder to use. But like the other options, generally require Accessibility is turned on in System Preferences. (unless you are able to run as root, which is almost never a good idea).